# Doxygen @file removes other command formatting except @brief

Tags: comments, doxygen

if I have a c header file with a doxygen comment:

```
/*!
*    @file    MyHeaderFile.h
*    @brief   Brief header file description
*    @author  Me Myself
*    @date    2012.4.16
*/
```

This results in html like this:

[image]

This same syntax works fine in function comments:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this all that is supported?

EDIT: normal function comment:

```
/*!
*    @brief This function does things
*
*    @author Me Myself
*    @date   2012.4.16
*   
*    @returns    void
*/
void MyFunctionThing(void)
{
}
```

Comment: You don't really ask a question. Is your question: is the markup for files and functions supposed to look the same? If so, this works fine for me: the markup looks the same for both functions and files. I think we'll need some more information to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if I am doing something wrong because the output is not as documented from my understanding. I use the same syntax for function and file but get different output. Why are my author and date commands not being formatted?

Comment: Can you show us some more of your code? Otherwise it is hard to tell why your are seeing the ouput you are. Also, do you get any warnings when running doxygen?

Comment: The only other code I have is for the function. That is all the code I have for the file comment block, I have added code for the function.

Comment: I get no warnings relating to this.

Comment: I have run the minimal example (the two documentation blocks are a function prototype and nothing else in a file) you have provided and I see the same output for both the function and the header file. Therefore the problem is elsewhere in your code or is in your configuration file settings. Is there anyway you could post a complete minimal example which reproduces the problem you are seeing?

Comment: I have found the issue. It occurs when I do the following:  /*!***********************

Comment: @Chris You can put that as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution, I don't like answering my own posts.

Comment: I don't think I should answer since you found the solution - [it is ok to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), the FAQ says so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I could not really reproduce the problem given your example, this is most likely the result of Markdown support (introduced in version 1.8.0), in particular the [code blocks feature](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_codeblock).
Options you can try to avoid/workaround this:

- Set MARKDOWN_SUPPORT to NO in the config file
- Indent the text in you comment block with less than 4 spaces (after the `*`).